# how to use .call() and .apply() for unlimited arguments In JS?

Tags: javascript, arguments, apply, call

```
curry = function (biFunc, ...args) {
  const test = (...arg) => {
    return biFunc(...args, ...arg);
  };
  return test;
};
```

and

```
composeU = function (u1,u2) {
 

  function test(number) {
    {
      return u2(u1(number));
    }
  }

  return test; 
};
```

please show me using these examples.
this is for a bootcamp im doing and part of the challenge is to use those methods I think to make the function usable with infinite numbers of parameters. curry is fine without any of those methods but for compose u I need to use each unary function passed in order.

ComposeU takes in two unary functions and calls them both in argument order.

Comment: Can you clarify what exactly `composeU` should do ? Can you add an example of how do you expect to use that function and what you already tried to do ?

Comment: `composeU` is incomplete. It does nothing with its `args`, and both `u1` and `u2` are undefined.

Comment: You need neither `call` nor `apply` for any of this when you use rest parameter and spread call syntax.

Comment: So what exactly is the challenge, and where are you stuck? Notice that the key to processing an arbitrary amount of passed functions is a loop.